# Have to click formula bar and hit enter before it recalculates

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 worksheets.

Worksheet 1: Nicely put up data with rows like this

- Row1: 5 <-- This data comes from sheet 2
- Row2: 4 <-- This data comes from sheet 2
- Row3: 2 <-- This data comes from sheet 2
- Row4: =(Row1+Row2+Row3)/3 <-- Simple calculation from above cells.

I have this macro

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If IsError(Cells(139, 8).Value) Then
    Call Sheet1.HideCharts
    End If

End Sub
```

This works perfectly, and runs when an error occured, so if i put =5/0 (which gives an error) in row 1, the HideCharts macro runs.

However.
The data comes from worksheet 2, and this data comes from cubes (database) and when that data changes to i.e. nothing, it will give #REF! on worksheet 1. which i understand is an error, however then the macro won't run. What am i doing wrong? I hope you understand my question.

- Edit: I found out that the macro actually semi-runs. It goes through however i have to double-click the cell and just press enter, and then it activates.

Comment: How is the data changed? Is it a formula that is being recalculated or a value being set by another macro?

Comment: I have sheet 2 where the data is imported from a database, where it is then put up nicely in sheet1, and from this data i have
Row1: 5 <-- caused by these
Row2: 3 <-- caused by these
Row3: 4 <-- caused by these
Average: =(5+3+4)/3 <-- When this changes - run macro

Comment: Can you clarify or elaborate the line in your question ~which works if i manually change the data of the cell, however i dont manually change the data.`

Comment: I tried to rephrase it, do you understand my question now?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

End Sub
```

or you could check the changes to the vals in the formula's the way you're checking the result maybe